# What is the difference between base_grand_total and grand_total?

Tags: magento2, grand-total

what is the difference between base_grand_total and grand_total?
What is base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base_grand_total` = Default store currency.

`grand_total` = current store currency (selected store currency).

`base_` it's for a default store currency.

If you have just one currency on your website, `base_grand_total` and `grand_total` will have the **same value**.